# Servlet.service() for servlet CXFServlet threw exception

Tags: java, spring, web-services, tomcat, jax-rs

I am using JaxRS webservice + spring application which deployed on tomcat.

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class> org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet 
    </servlet-class>
```

I have been facing this issue at times, However when i restart web application works fine without these exceptions.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet CXFServlet threw exception
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:21)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:233)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:206)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:236)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.read(NioChannel.java:125)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:156)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:229)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:210)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.readSocket(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:571)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:868)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:892)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:830)
        at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:428)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:298)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:405)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:313)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:162)
        at com.fusionone.filter.BufferedRequestWrapper.<init>(RequestResponseLoggerFilter.java:256)
        at com.fusionone.filter.RequestResponseLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestResponseLoggerFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.fusionone.filter.RequestLogFilter.doFilter(RequestLogFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:879)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:719)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:2080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Jan 27, 2016 12:25:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
```

Some one please help me to understand this issue.

Comment: What are you doing to provoke this exception?

Comment: Application handle the request from clients(example..web client) and send to other application (deployed on other internal server) and get back with the response.

Comment: Did you have a real problem when that error occurs or is it just something you see in the log? Basically, this just tell you the client connected to tomcat is not here anymore (browser closed, timeout,...) so Tomcat can't send the response.

Comment: @Cédric Couralet Not really a problem, but it would be good to have some understanding over application errors. Not sure why is this happening ? is because of client closes the connection before server response OR do to  the server response time elapsed to give response  and then client closed the connection

Comment: @santoshMaddela Could be both, Tomcat can't send the response as the previously open socket to do it is now close. This means the client closed the connection. Typically, we see this when the webapp is too long to respond, so the user quits the tab. In your case, as it is a webservice, it could be a timeout on the client side. My rule of thumbs on that error is that if no one complains and it doesn't appear a lot (from context) then it is not serious.